# Syracuse sequence using recursive python functions

Tags: python, algorithm, recursion

the problem is as follows, we get a positive integer, we keep modifying it until we get 1, if the integer is pair we divide by 2, if impair we multiply by 3 and add 1, i was able to solve this using a while loop, but it seems i can't do it using recursion

here's the code:

```
def syracus(N):
    s = [N]
    if N==1:
        return s
    else: 
        if N%2==0:
            s.append(syracus(N/2))
            return s
            return syracus(N/2)
        
        elif N%2==1:
            s.append(syracus(3*N+1))
            return s
            return syracus(3*N+1)
```

here's the output

```
[15, [46, [23, [70, [35, [106, [53, [160, [80, [40, [20, [10, [5, [16, [8, [4, [2, [1]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason you get nested lists is that you *append* the result from recursion. But that recursive call returns a *list*, so you're appending a list to a list, which introduces the nesting. Instead, use `extend`.

There are a few other issues:

- As Python 2 is deprecated, we should not use `/` anymore for integer division, but `//`, otherwise you get results with float data type numbers instead of int data type.
- You have dead code: the statement that follows immediately after your `return s` will never get executed. Remove it (at both occurrences).
- The condition `N%2==1` will always evaluate to True when execution gets there. This is the only other possibility when the condition `N%2==0` is False, so just use `else` instead of that `elif`.
- Avoid code repeititon. You have `return s` at three places. It is easy to move that out of any condition, so that it always gets executed, no matter what the case is.
- The name `s` is obscure. It suggests a string data type, but it actually is a list. I would suggest a different name, like `lst`.
- It is more pythonic to give the parameter a lowercase name, so `n` instead of `N`

So, with those corrections we get:

```
def syracus(n):
    lst = [n]
    if n > 1:
        if n % 2 == 0:
            lst.extend(syracus(n // 2))
        else:
            lst.extend(syracus(3 * n +  1))
    return lst

print(syracus(15))
```

This is however creating a new list for every call of `syracus`. You could avoid this by first getting the list from the recursive call, and then appending `N` to it. At the end you'll need to reverse that result:

```
def syracus(n):
    def recur(n):
        if n == 1:
            lst = []
        elif n % 2 == 0:
            lst = syracus(n // 2)
        else:
            lst = syracus(3 * n + 1)
        lst.append(n)
        return lst

    return recur(n)[::-1]
    
print(syracus(15))
```

It is however more pythonic to use a generator for this, and that way you avoid creating a list at all during the algorithm. It is then up to the caller to create the list, if that is desired.

```
def syracus(n):
    yield n
    if n > 1:
        if n % 2 == 0:
            yield from syracus(n // 2)
        else:
            yield from syracus(3 * n + 1)
    
print(list(syracus(15)))
```

Answer (score 0):

> *"... i was able to solve this using a while loop, but it seems i can't do it using recursion ..."*

Here is an example using a *loop*.

```py
l = []
v = 27
while v != 1:
    l.append(v)
    v = int(v / 2) if not v % 2 else (v * 3) + 1
l.append(1)
```

And, here is an example using *recursion*.

```py
l = []
def f(v):
    l.append(v)
    if v != 1:
        f(int(v / 2) if not v % 2 else (v * 3) + 1)
```

Output

```
[27, 82, 41, 124, 62, 31, 94, 47, 142, 71, 214, 107, 322, 161, 484, 242, 121,
 364, 182, 91, 274, 137, 412, 206, 103, 310, 155, 466, 233, 700, 350, 175, 526,
 263, 790, 395, 1186, 593, 1780, 890, 445, 1336, 668, 334, 167, 502, 251, 754,
 377, 1132, 566, 283, 850, 425, 1276, 638, 319, 958, 479, 1438, 719, 2158, 1079,
 3238, 1619, 4858, 2429, 7288, 3644, 1822, 911, 2734, 1367, 4102, 2051, 6154,
 3077, 9232, 4616, 2308, 1154, 577, 1732, 866, 433, 1300, 650, 325, 976, 488,
 244, 122, 61, 184, 92, 46, 23, 70, 35, 106, 53, 160, 80, 40, 20, 10, 5, 16, 8,
 4, 2, 1]
```

Answer (score 0):

Easily made recursive by concatenating a single element list containing the number, with the content of the next steps in the sequence (stopping when 1 is reached):

```
def syracuse(N):
    return [1] if N==1 else [N] + syracuse(N*3+1 if N%2 else N//2)

print(syracuse(15))
[15, 46, 23, 70, 35, 106, 53, 160, 80, 40, 20, 10, 5, 16, 8, 4, 2, 1]
```

Answer (score -1):

In base case where `N==1` must returns a list containing only `[1]`.
Otherwise return `[N] + syracus(...)` which gonna concatenate the current value of `N` with the result of the recursive call:

```
def syracus(N):
    if N == 1:
        return [1]
    else:
        if N % 2 == 0:
            return [N] + syracus(N // 2)
        else:
            return [N] + syracus(3 * N + 1)

result = syracus(15)
print(result)#[15, 46, 23, 70, 35, 106, 53, 160, 80, 40, 20, 10, 5, 16, 8, 4, 2, 1]
```